# UWP SerialDevice.FromIdAsync return null

Tags: serial-port, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I'm trying the Microsoft sample for Serial Port and it's working on Raspberry Pi2 but not on local machine , on,local machine return null.

the DeviceCapability already added, that's why it's working on Pi2.

any idea why it's not working on local machine

local system:
Win10 Ent.
VS 2015.3

Answer (score 3):

I found this answer :(

[Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.serialcommunication.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> System-internal or on-chassis serial ports may be enumerated by DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(), but cannot be opened by SerialDevice.FromIdAsync() because they currently are not supported. However, serial ports connected over USB, such as on USB-to-Serial cables are supported.

Update :
the issue still there even after the updates untill now

> Serial ports marked as internal to the machine
> (DEVPKEY_Device_InLocalMachineContainer == TRUE) are not accessible
> unless explictly marked by the vendor driver as unrestricted
> (DEVPKEY_DeviceInterface_Restricted == TRUE). Devices connect via most
> PCI COM port expansion cards are therefore not accessible.
>
> Inaccessible serial ports may still be enumerated by
> DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(), but cannot be opened by
> SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(). Attemping to open such a device will
> either throw an exception or return null. Apps should handle this case
> by filtering such serial ports from the user's view, so that the user
> will not be able to interact with such an unsupported serial port.

Comment: @lindexi You too.