# UsbDevice.FromIdAsync returning null in UWP app

Tags: windows, uwp, usb, iot

I'm currently working on an UWP app which includes USB communication with a custom USB device. I was able to set up a communication channel between a Raspberry Pi 3b and the device and sent some bytes back and forth. It does not work if I run this app on a local machine (Windows 10 build 1809) instead. In this case the call to [UsbDevice.FromIdAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.usb.usbdevice.fromidasync) always returns NULL.

I saw some related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427148/usbdevice-fromidasync-returns-null), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28721091/c-sharp-windows-store-app-returning-null-for-usbdevice) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319056/uwp-serialdevice-fromidasync-return-null) with the similar or even the same problem. But none of the solutions mentioned are working for me.

I installed the Win USB driver using following inf-file:

```
;
; Installs WinUsb
;
[Version]
Signature = "$Windows NT$"
Class     = USBDevice
ClassGUID = {88BAE032-5A81-49f0-BC3D-A4FF138216D6}
Provider  = %ManufacturerName%
CatalogFile = WinUSBInstallation.cat
DriverVer = 12/12/2016,13.54.20.543

[Generic.Section.NTamd64]
%USB\MS_COMP_WINUSB.DeviceDesc% = WINUSB,USB\MS_COMP_WINUSB 

; ========== Manufacturer/Models sections ===========

[Manufacturer]
%ManufacturerName% = Standard,NTamd64

[Standard.NTamd64]
%DeviceName% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0483&PID_0001

; ========== Class definition ===========

[ClassInstall32]
AddReg = ClassInstall_AddReg

[ClassInstall_AddReg]
HKR,,,,%ClassName%
HKR,,NoInstallClass,,1
HKR,,SilentInstall,,1 
HKR,,IconPath,%REG_MULTI_SZ%,"%systemroot%\system32\setupapi.dll,-20"
HKR,,LowerLogoVersion,,5.2

; =================== Installation ===================

[USB_Install]
Include = winusb.inf
Needs   = WINUSB.NT

[USB_Install.Services]
Include = winusb.inf
Needs   = WINUSB.NT.Services

[USB_Install.HW]
AddReg = Dev_AddReg

[Dev_AddReg]
HKR,,DeviceInterfaceGUIDs,0x10000,"{9f543223-cede-4fa3-b376-a25ce9a30e74}"

; =================== Strings ===================

[Strings]
ManufacturerName = "Manufacturer"
ClassName = "Universal Serial Bus devices"
DeviceName = "Device"
REG_MULTI_SZ = 0x00010000
```

The device shows up properly in the device manager without any errors.
I added the device capabilities to the Package.appxmanifest as follows:

```
<Capabilities>
  <DeviceCapability Name="usb">
    <Device Id="vidpid:0483 0001">
      <Function Type="classId:ff 00 00"/>
      <Function Type="name:vendorSpecific"/>
    </Device>
  </DeviceCapability>
</Capabilities>
```

And in my code I try to open the device as follows:

```cs
byte deviceClass = 0xff;
byte deviceSubclass = 0x00;

var myDevices = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(
    Windows.Devices.Usb.UsbDevice.GetDeviceClassSelector(
        new Windows.Devices.Usb.UsbDeviceClass() {
            ClassCode = deviceClass,
            SubclassCode = deviceSubclass
        }
    )
);

UsbDevice device = null;
var numDevices = myDevices.Count;

foreach (var d in myDevices) {
    device = await UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(d.Id);
    if (device == null) {
        // Device could not be found.
    }
    else {
        // Found device.
    }
}
```

The call to FindAllAsync does find a single device which has the correct id. But calling FromIdAsync always returns NULL. As mentioned before this all works on a Raspberry Pi 3b but not locally on my desktop machine or any other machine I tried out.
I searched for a few days now and I don't know what I'm still overlooking or missing. Any suggestions what else I can do?

Best regards

Comment: I have tested with official code [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomUsbDeviceAccess), it works well, could you test  this  in another usb socket.

Comment: I tried different sockets with the same result. Executing the example returns the device access status "DeniedByUser". I included the corresponding snippet regarding the device access information into my code and got the same error. It this somehow related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54397934/cant-find-seiralport-device-by-using-serialdevice-fromidasync-and-got-imforma) question? I tried it, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Please share more about use device, such as product name model name and interface type.

Comment: The device is a custom developement, supporting USB 2.0. The data itself shall be transferred using interrupt-transfer. The funny things is, in a different application in which we utilize the [WinUSB library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winusb/index) and SetupApi, it also works.

Comment: hmm, if you could not provide the usb device detail  info, we could not test it completely.